# Huge graph exercise with binary operations

Tags: algorithm

So I've come across the following problem:

Lets `G` be a graph with `2^N` vertices labeled `0` to `2^N-1`. It's a directed acyclic graph and in order for there to be a path from `a` to `b` the following two conditions must apply:

1. `a < b`
2. `a XOR b` (in binary) = `2^x`, where `x>=0`

I need to determine the total number of paths of length `K` (all edges have length `1`).
The input consists of `N` and `K`.

The easy way to count the number of paths of length `K` would be to look at `G` as any other graph and use the conditions to determine which vertices are connected. However, the task requires that `N` and `K` be of size `2<=K<=N<=100000`.

`2^100000` is a bit too much, so there has to be a better way to calculate this. Also I'm limited to an execution time of `200` ms.

Example: For `N = 4` and `K = 2`, the result is `48`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Presumably you mean "labeled 0 to 2*N - 1"?

Comment: if only `N` and `K` are given i would assume some average or statistical answer is sought, since any other answer would require the exact graph to be given

Comment: @PieterGeerkens 2 to the power of N, not 2*N.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically we need to find how many `x0 < x1 < ... < xk < 2^N` there are such that:

```
xi xor xi+1 = 2^x
```

Note that for the `xor` of two numbers to be a power of 2, the result of the xor must contain exactly 1 bit set. Therefore, the 2 numbers must differ in only one position (otherwise, more positions would be set in the xor, because `xor` returns 1 only when the operands are different bits).

Let's assume we start at `0`. We can move from it to any node labeled with a power of `2`.

From that node, we can then move to any node that has set bits in the position of the current node's set bits and a set bit somewhere else. This goes on, taking into account that we must generate the sequence in increasing order.

For example:

```
000 -> 001 -> 011 -> 111
           -> 101 -> 111
    -> 010 -> 011 -> 111
           -> 110 -> 111
    -> 100 -> 101 -> 111
           -> 110 -> 111
=> 6 = 3! solutions

0000 -> 0001 -> 0011 -> 0111 -> 1111
                     -> 1011 -> 1111
             -> 0101 -> 1101 -> 1111
                     -> 0111 -> 1111
             -> 1001 -> 1011 -> 1111
                     -> 1101 -> 1111
=> 6 solutions
=> another 3*6 for the other 3 possibilities from 0000
=> 24 solutions
```

So, in order to get a path of length `k`, you need to start from an integer with at least `k` unset (0) bits.

So you can find out how many `n-bit` integers have at least `k` unset bits, find out how many possibilities there are to pick `k` from those, and multiply that answer by `k!`.

To find how many `n-bit` integers have **exactly** `k'` unset bits, you can use the binomial coefficient:

```
Binomial(n, k') = n! / [k'!*(n - k')!]
```

You will also need to multiply this by `Binomial(k', k)` in order to decide which `k` bits you'll be using.

You'll need to sum this for `k' = k to n` and multiply the sum by `k!`.

Those are going to be some huge numbers. I'm guessing you're asked for the result modulo a prime, in which case you'll have to use modular multiplicative inverses.

Comment: This seems promising and yes I am in fact needed to return the result modulo 100003.

I've added a test case in my question. For `N = 4` and `K=2`, the expected result is `48`.

I'm not sure if I am miscalculating, but according to your method I am getting:

`(Binomial(4,2)+Binomial(4,3)+Binomial(4,4))*2! = (6+4+1)*2 = 22`

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: @IVlad you're missing a factor Binomial(k', k) in the sums. If a number has k' unset bits, there's Binomial(k', k) * k! paths of length k starting from it. Total paths is K! * sum_{k'} [Binomial(n, k') * Binomial(k', K)]. For N=4, K=2 this gives 2! * (Bin(4,2)*Bin(2, 2) + Bin(4, 3)*Bin(3, 2) + Bin(4, 4)*Bin(4,2)) = 2 * (6 + 12 + 6) = 48.

Comment: @user2980055 - Anonymous, is correct, I forgot a factor. Edited it, thanks.